# Find all minimal candidate keys of R

Tags: database, functional-dependencies, database-theory

I have a `R= {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K}`  `F={ABGH->IJKF,JIGH->ABF, A->CDE}` I need to find all minimal candidate keys of `R`, and How to normalize `R` to BCNF

I got the following answers so far:
`ABGH`, `GHJIK` and `AGHIJK`.

But I was check my answer from this site :[checked site](http://www.koffeinhaltig.com/fds/kandidatenschluessel.php?attrs=A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K&fds=A+B+G+H+-%3E+I+J+K+F%2C+J+I+G+H+-%3E+A+B+F%2C+A+-%3E+C+D+E&language=en)

I don't know why 'K' is not part of the answer and I am not sure if my answers were correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two candidate keys of R: {ABGH} and {GHIJ}.

{GHJIK} is not a candidate key, but if it *were*, then {AGHIJK} would not be a minimal  key.

The attribute K isn't part of the two candidate keys, because the closure of {ABGH} contains K, and the closure of {GHIJ} contains K.  For example, for {ABGH} . . .

```
ABGH->ABGH (trivial)
ABGH->IJKF (given), therefore
ABGH->ABGHIJKF
A->CDE (given), therefore
ABGH->ABCDEGHIJKF, or in alpha order
ABGH->ABCDEFGHIJK
```

Answer (score 0):

BCNF decomposition will be 
R1 (ACDE) nd R2(ABFGHIJK)
because in R (A--> CDE) is partial dependency. So we decompose it in R1 where A is ck and R2 where ABGH and GHIJ are candidate keys.

Answer (score 0):

Any no. of attributes added to candidate key forms a super key. We can also thus say that candidate key is the minimal super key. Here `ABGH` and `GHIJ` can determine all other attributes of the relation so they become candidate keys hence `GHIJK` becomes a super key (due to addition of `K`) and not a candidate key and on similar principles `AGHIJK` (due to addition of `A` and `K`) also becomes a super key as it has `GHIJ` which is a candidate key.